# How do you pass a variable from a text box in html and use it in php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a chatroom in html and php i have it working but it can only post to one page and i want it to be able to post to different pages that the user chooses by typing the page name into a textbox in a html form
and puting there name position and message here is the code i have so far

```
                        <?php
                        if($_POST) {
                          $Chatroom_name = $_POST['Chatroom'];
                          $position = $_POST['position'];
                          $name = $_POST['name'];
                          $content = $_POST['commentContent']             
    want variable here--->$handle = fopen('$Chatroom_name',"a");





                          fwrite($handle,"<b>" . $name . "</b>:<br/>" .                             $position . "</b>:<br/>" . $content . "<br/><br><br>");
                          fclose($handle);





                        }
                        ?>

                        <html>
                        <head>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                        <br><br><br>


                        <form name="chatroomname" action = "" method = "POST">
                        Chatroom Name: <br>
                         <input type = "text" name = "Chatroom"><br>
                        Name:<br>
                         <input type = "text" name = "name"><br/>
                        Position:<br>
                         <input type = "text" name = "position"><br/>
                        Message:<br>
                         <textarea rows = "10" cols = "30" name = "commentContent"></textarea><br/>
                         <input type = "submit" value = "Send"><br/>
                      </form>

                     </body>
                    </html>
```

can someone please help me it is for a big project i am doing 
any help is greatly apriciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You should set your form's `action` to point to the name of this file. That way when you submit the form it'll reload the page and send the `POST` data along with it.

You can output the variable's content into the form by doing something like this:

```
<input type = "text" name = "Chatroom" value="<?php if(isset($Chatroom_name)){ echo $Chatroom_name; }">
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answere but do you thing you could please give an example i am a newbie to php

Comment: Say for example that your file above is named `chat.php`, set the `action` property on the `form` to be `action="chat.php"`. Obviously change it to whatever it is actually called.

Comment: i dont know what i am doing wrong it still wont work

Comment: The variables will be getting set, but you're not displaying them in the code. You can do an `if` statement and use it to set a `value` attribute on each input to put the value back in. I've edited my original post.

Comment: im sorry but im now getting a sytax error

Comment: Sorry I missed out a bracket, have edited the original post.

Comment: sorry i dont know what is going on it wont work do you think you might be able to put it in my page above and put it in the comments so i can see what i might be doing wron if you dont what to i understand

Comment: Please paste your code [here](http://phpfiddle.org/) and share the link.

Comment: where do i get the link sir

Answer (score 0):

You should use sessions in php.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
}
```

In further pages, just make sure you start the session, and then echo the variable.

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['name']; //this will print the name submitted
```

Comment: i am confused on where i might put this can you pleas point me in the right direction

Comment: just after the variables you assigned

Comment: `$Chatroom_name = $_POST['Chatroom'];
$position = $_POST['position'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$content = $_POST['commentContent'];
session_start(); `
and store as many variables in session as you want.

Comment: i am trying my hardest to understand what this is doing can you please help me sir

Comment: yeah sure, you want the user to fill his name and other details, and you want to show those details on each page you make for chat system? is it so

Comment: yes but my problem is that i dont know how to make it post to another page by using a variable from a text box like if i wanted to post on a page called programing.html i could type it in the first box and fill in all the forms and send it to that page that is what i am trying to achieve

Comment: just fill the name once in for example, first.html 
`<form name="chatroomname" action = "second.php" method = "POST">
                        Chatroom Name: <br>
                         <input type = "text" name = "Chatroom"><br>
                        Name:
                         <input type = "text" name = "name">
                        Position:<input type = "text" name = "position"> Message<textarea rows = "10" cols = "30" name = "commentContent"></textarea><input type = "submit" value = "Send" name="submit"></form>`

Comment: In second.php use the code 
<?php
                        if($_POST) {
                          $Chatroom_name = $_POST['Chatroom'];
                          $position = $_POST['position'];
                          $name = $_POST['name'];
                          $content = $_POST['commentContent'];
session_start();
and the code which i mentioned earlier in the answer

Comment: Can you please put it together for me i am in great need of your asistaince i really dont want to get it wrong again sir